# LocalStorage output is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am building a shopping website. Therefore I am using the local storage. Now I use JSON for my products and they have a value of the quantity called "menge". Every time I click on "add to cart" the value of "menge" increases by one. But later when I want to print the quantity on the shopping cart the value is always 0.

Here the Code of the "add to cart" button

```
const el = document.getElementById('Knopfwarenkorb1');
el.addEventListener('click', () =>{
produkt[0].menge +=1;
zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(produkt[0])
```

produkt[] is my Array with my products.

here is the code of the function:

```
function zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(produkt) {
  let warenkorb = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('warenkorb'));

  if (warenkorb) {
    warenkorb.push(produkt)
    localStorage.setItem('warenkorb', JSON.stringify(warenkorb));
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('warenkorb', JSON.stringify([produkt]));
  }
}
```

Comment: when you do push, you put it at the end of the array, so if it makes sense that the first element will always be the initial number.

Comment: So how can I fix it ?